# Retrieve unique "LIKES" on facebook Insights for Domain

Tags: facebook, feedback

I was wondering if it was possible to get the number of unique "LIKES" when using Facebook Insights for Domain?

Insight tell me i have 240 likes but on my like button i get 7500+ because of "Feedback from Share". If there a simple way that i can have an automated script get the 240 "Likes" as opposed to the "Feedback from Likes" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link_stats table in FQL.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

-Roozbeh

Comment: I've tried that but it give me the same result as using "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=MY_LINK".. Still no variable about the UNIQUE share number, it's the same number as "Feedback from shares"